# OrderedDictionary and Regex

Tags: c#, regex, ordereddictionary

I have a problem with `orderedDictionary` and `Regex`. How can I define the problem by text but I'll try to explain...

**This is my code:**

```
var smilies = new OrderedDictionary
{
    {@":(", "smile_sadx24"},
    {@">:(", "smile_angryx24"},
};

foreach (string smiley in smilies.Keys)
{
    var re = new Regex(@"(?<!(=""))" + Regex.Escape(smiley) + @"(?<!(""))");
    if (re.IsMatch(incomingtext))
    {
        string m2 = re.Replace(incomingtext, "<img src=\"/Content/themes/mavi/img/custom/smiles/" + smilies[smiley] + ".png\"  alt=\"" + smiley + "\"/>");
        incomingtext = m2;
    }
}
```

When I tried to process `>:(` then  it returned `smile_sadx24` not `smile_angryx24`...

Because it catch `:(` firstly...

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try putting the angry smiley first in the dictionary perhaps?

Comment: Tried already. No effect :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

```
var smilies = new OrderedDictionary
{
    {@">:(", "smile_angryx24"},  // Put this one first
    {@":(", "smile_sadx24"},
};

foreach (string smiley in smilies.Keys)
{
    var re = new Regex(@"(?<!(=""))" + Regex.Escape(smiley) + @"(?!(""))"); 
                       // Second should be a negative lookahead  ^^
    if (re.IsMatch(incomingtext))
    {
        string m2 = re.Replace(incomingtext, "<img src=\"/Content/themes/mavi/img/custom/smiles/" + smilies[smiley] + ".png\"  alt=\"" + smiley + "\"/>");
        incomingtext = m2;
    }
}
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/aWdOIJ)

Using a negative look *behind* where there was supposed to be a lookahead was what caused the regex to fail when you swapped the angry and sad smileys, because the smiley characters aren't using `"` at all.